# Break on error/exception with python remote development in Visual Studio Code (vscode)

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

How do I enable an automatic breakpointing when an exception occurs in vscode **python**?  I am using remote development on vscode 1.42.1.

I can accomplish this using pdb directly with `python -m pdb -c continue myscript.py`, but I would like to step through with the vscode editor.